# need to get output without braces '{'

Tags: python-3.x, label, strip

Opening a text file that has no bracers in it. The program reads the lines and displays data with braces.

```
Example in my.txt file:
name
address
city state zip
phone


after code to read outputs to a label I get:
    {name}
    {address}
    {city} {state} {zip}
    {phone}

I would like it to read:
    name
    address
    city state zip
    phone
```

I have tried strip()
I have tried to see if pprint has anything. 
code is as follows:

```
def readprofile():
    profin = open("pbreg.txt", "r")
    msgstored = profin.readlines()
    data_label["text"] = msgstored
    profin.close()

after code to read, it outputs to a label with braces:
    {name}
    {address}
    {city} {state} {zip}
    {phone}

I would like it to read:
    name
    address
    city state zip
    phone
```

Comment: How do you read the output exactly?

Comment: def readprofile():
    profin = open("pbreg.txt", "r")
    msgstored = profin.readlines()

###lots of code here###

readprofile()
root.mainloop()

Comment: figured it out...OMG so easy def readprofile():
    with open("pbreg.txt") as profin:
        msgstored = profin.read()
        data_label["text"] = msgstored